# Checking if an integral converges (or diverges) using dimensional analysis

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dimensional-analysis

I have been watching some online lectures in Physics, and the lecturer uses dimensional analysis to make claims such as the following:

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(\xi, d) = \int_0^\xi \frac{\mathrm{d}^\mathrm{d}q}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{q^2(q^2+1)}\quad\text{where}\quad q=|\boldsymbol{q}|.
\end{equation}

It is claimed that

1. The "measure of the integral" is $\xi^{d-4}$, hence $I$ is a constant for $2<d<4$ in the limit $\xi\to\infty$
2. Using the above, $I$ diverges with $\xi$ for $d>4$
3. When $d=4$ (then"marginal case"), $I\sim\log(\xi)$

I recognise that these claims are imprecise: but that's exactly my question! How is such dimensional analysis used to determine the convergence or lack thereof of integrals in arbitrary dimension $d$? What does the "measure of the integral" mean? Furthermore, how do we know that there is no divergence due to the singularity at the origin?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735637/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to analyze these kind of integrals is to consider the $d^d q$ integration as radial (since there is no angular component to $q^2$ (actually $|\vec q|^2$). So that up to $\pi$'s etc  $d^d q \sim q^{d-1} dq$. Now consider
$$ \int_0^\xi dq {q^{d-1} \over q^2 (1+q^2)}.$$
The lower bound is controlled as long as $d>2$ as expected.
For the upper bound, the term $(1+q^2)$ can be approximated as $q^2$ so the tail of the integral behaves like ${q^{d-1}\over q^4} =q^{d-5}$ so the integral diverges when $d>4$.

At $d=4$ the integral *still diverges* but as $\int^\xi q^{-1}\sim \log(\xi)$ This is called "marginal" because it is not a power divergence, so that reasonable "controlling" of the integral towards infinity could turn this into a convergent integral.